# uploading multiple files atempt is only uploading one - debugging the problem

Tags: php, html, forms, email-attachments

I've got a working php script for attaching a single file to an e-mail and was trying to use if for attaching multiple files. In fact, I originally wrote the script to allow multiple attachments (it loops through $_FILES and does an addAttachment for each  but never specified "multiple" in the html form. I was hoping that it would just work when I did add "multiple" and it appears to (the "browse" button shows the number of files I selected correctly) but when I do a var_dump of the $_FILES array, it only shows the last file selected:

```
array (size=1)
  'uploaded_file' => 
   array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'stock-photo-overhead-view-on-colorful-car-toys-278195099.jpg' (length=60)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpMjwuvu' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 54640
```

In fact, the var_dump just confirms what I was seeing in my testing - I'd get an e-mail with just one file attached (the last file in the selection list).

I found another post here that suggested adding "[]" after the name attribute of the file input element. It eventually worked when I also added it after the element id. However, script then fails because it has only one array element in $_FILES but the array elements each are now arrays:

```
array (size=1)
  'uploaded_file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '84682528.jpg' (length=12)
          1 => string 'Screenshot_20180516_194429.png' (length=30)
          2 => string 'stock-photo-overhead-view-on-colorful-car-toys-278195099.jpg' (length=60)
      'type' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          1 => string 'image/png' (length=9)
          2 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '/tmp/phpr3syrP' (length=14)
          1 => string '/tmp/phpQ75amr' (length=14)
          2 => string '/tmp/phpoYggi3' (length=14)
      'error' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 0
          2 => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 67951
          1 => int 57707
          2 => int 54640
```

My interpretation of this is that $_FILES will contain one array element for each file input element, with each array element possibly being an array if multiple files were selected in that element. While this makes a certain amount of sense, it means that the programmer doesn't know how many files were uploaded without querying each $_FILES array element.

It also (I believe) means that you need to use different code depending on whether the file input form elements (name, type, etc.) are arrays or not.

Anyway, I'm just posting this in case someone else runs into the same issue. It may save them some time. Now that I've found the problem, on to fixing it....

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if the $_FILES array has more than one items and build a new array of each uploaded file with their corresponding attributes (type, size, ...).

**Example :**

**UPLOADED FILES :**

```
<?php

$_FILES['uploaded_file'] = [

    "name" => [
        "84682528.jpg",
        "Screenshot_20180516_194429.png",
        "stock-photo-overhead-view-on-colorful-car-toys-278195099.jpg"
    ],
    "type" => [
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/png",
        "image/jpeg"
    ],
    "tmp_name" => [
        "/tmp/phpr3syrP",
        "/tmp/phpQ75amr",
        "/tmp/phpoYggi3"
    ],
    "error" => [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "size" => [
        67951, 
        57707, 
        54640
    ]
];

?>
```

**EXTRACT EACH FILE WITH ITS ATTRIBUTES**

```
<?php
    
    $uploadedFiles = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
    
    $files = [];
    
    if(count($uploadedFiles) > 1) {
    
        foreach($uploadedFiles['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $files[$key]['name'] = $name;
            $files[$key]['type'] = $uploadedFiles['type'][$key];
            $files[$key]['tmp_name'] = $uploadedFiles['tmp_name'][$key];
            $files[$key]['error'] = $uploadedFiles['error'][$key];
            $files[$key]['size'] = $uploadedFiles['size'][$key];
        }
    
    } else {
        // Handle single uploaded file
    }
    
    var_dump($files);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "84682528.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpr3syrP"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(67951)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(30) "Screenshot_20180516_194429.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpQ75amr"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(57707)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(60) "stock-photo-overhead-view-on-colorful-car-toys-278195099.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpoYggi3"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(54640)
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't really looking for an answer - just felt that I should point out the issue. Your suggestion doesn't quite work any more than my original code did, just for the opposite reason. My original code worked if there was only file per $_FILES  array element  while your response begins by assuming only one $_FILES array element.

The solution I'm working on does the inverse of your solution - I'm grabbing the individual file information within each file input element, so rather than constructing an array, I pass the individual file details to a function to add them as an attachment.

Comment: The point is to make it as generic as possible - to allow people to attach zero or  multiple files in a file input element while also allowing for multiple file input elements (each with potentially zero or multiple files).

The whole thing would easier if the $FILES array simply put each file as a separate array element.... But I didn't write that standard.  ;)

Comment: I am not getting the out put